# Initialize a C++ class using its constructor inside another Classes constructor that references it

Tags: c++, constructor, reference

I have a class Foo that references Bar:

```
class Foo {
  Bar &bar;
};
```

and bar requires an int& to be constructed:

```
Class Bar {
  Bar(int& required_int);
}
```

I want to be able to initialize Bar when I initalize Foo, but I cannot seem to do so using either of the following:

```
Foo::Foo(int &my_int) : bar(my_int) {
//...
}

Foo::Foo(int &my_int) : bar(new Bar(my_int)) {
//...
}
```

Because the compiler complains that whatever is inside `bar(...)` must be an lvalue. Is this initalization chaining possible? I don't see how `bar(...)` could ever contain an lvalue if my instance of Bar doesn't exist yet.

Comment: "if my instance of Bar doesn't exist yet" - well, that's the problem. Your usage of Bar assumes that you are operating on an existing instance of this class. If you want `Foo` to have its own `Bar` instance, use `Bar bar;`

Comment: Just pilling on with a slightly different viewpoint. An object of type `Foo` requires an object of type `Bar`, because a properly constructed reference is one that points to an object. Your choices are either to _own_ an instance of `Bar`, or point to one (bringing a danger of inefficiency and crashes when the pointer is invalid) or construct a `Foo` by passing a reference to an already constructed `Bar`

Answer (score 2):

```
class Foo {
    Bar & bar;
};
```

Here `bar` can only refer to an existing `Bar` object as it's a reference. You cannot initialize it yourself in Foo class. So, a valid ctor would be similar to this:

```
Foo::Foo(Bar & existingBar) : bar(existingBar){}
```

If you want `Foo` class to have its own independent `Bar` object, then remove the reference and initialize it like you're doing already.